# Type hinting in class variables

Tags: php, oop, type-hinting

```
<?php

namespace Sandbox;

class Sandbox {

    private Connectors\ISandboxConnector $connection;

    public function __construct(Connectors\ISandboxConnector $conn) {
        $this->connection = $conn;
    }

}

?>
```

For the above code I'm getting the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Connectors' (T_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)
```

When I remove the type hinting and `var_dump` that $connection variable, it will be `private Sandbox\Sandbox` and not `Sandbox\Connectors\ISandboxconnector`, why?

Comment: Seems like two separate questions here. No, that type hint on the property is not valid; you cannot type hint properties. Discounting that part of the question, can you clarify and better demonstrate the other part?

Comment: I'm not sure what other part I suggested? Knowing that you can't type hint properties is all I needed to know.. (If you make it an answer I'll accept it)

Comment: *"When I remove the type hinting and var_dump that $connection variable, it will be private Sandbox\Sandbox and not Sandbox\Connectors\ISandboxconnector, why?"* ← That part.

Comment: Ahh yes, but now that I know it ignores the type I wanted, it falls back to it's class. So then it makes sense.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

PHP 7.3 and below does not support typed properties. You could only define a variable as below:

```
class Sandbox {
    private $connection;
```

However, to help editors understand your code, you may use a [`@var`](https://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/PHP/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.var.pkg.html) tag to document the expected type of the property:

```
class Sandbox {
    /** @var Connectors\ISandboxConnector */
    private $connection;
```

---

#### Update

**PHP 7.4.0**

Thanks @Manuel for mentioning the new update, PHP 7.4 now introduces typed properties according to [PHP RFC: Typed Properties 2.0](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/typed_properties_v2).

Property type declarations support all type declarations supported by PHP, with the exception of `void` and `callable`. Any class or interface name, stdClass, scalar and compound types, references to parent and own objects are also supported.

```
class Sandbox {
    public int $id;
    public string $name;
    private Connectors\ISandboxConnector $connection;
}
```

**Note:** keep an eye on side effects such as uninitialised state and inheritance strict rules.

Comment: Works in Netbeans.

Comment: Works in PhpStorm.

Comment: I just published an article about all the available type hinting types vs PHP version: https://mlocati.github.io/articles/php-type-hinting.html

Comment: They should add type hinting to variables. They have it for function parameters, so why stop there.

Answer (score 2):

Since PHP 7.4 you are able to type hint on class properties, as shown [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.new-features.php#migration74.new-features.core.typed-properties). So for example your `$connection` property would look like this:

```
class Sandbox {
    private Connectors\ISandboxConnector $connection;
}
```