# PHP Class as a Parameter of another class

Tags: php

I'm sorry for what is probably an easy question, but I'm having trouble finding anything about it on the web.  I have two classes, for the purposes of this post let's call them user and address, looking like this:

```
class user {
  public $firstName;
  public $lastName;
  public $address;
}

class address{
  public $streetAddress;
  public $streetName;
  public $city;
  public $state;
  public $zip;
}
```

In this case, I want the $address parameter in the user class to be of type "address" defined by the second class.  Can I do this in PHP?  My end goal is to be able to consume properties like this:

```
$userZip = $user->address->zip;
```

Am I on the right track or way off?

Comment: have you tried it? A property can be of any type you want. So the answer is yes, you can access a property like this. You would just need to set the value in a constructor.

Comment: example: http://codepad.org/woJEXbHm edit: I changed the indentation to spaces so it is easier to read.

Comment: [Type hinting](http://php.net/manual/de/language.oop5.typehinting.php) for class properties hasn't been implemented yet (as of php 7.0.4). I therefore believe that the best you can do regarding _pinning_ the property type is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18956588/type-hinting-in-class-variables  ...if _that_ is your actual question.

Comment: I believe what they're asking is whether or not a class property can be an instance of another class. The short answer is yes.

Comment: Apparently so ;-) The comment "but how does that establish that the parameter in the first class is of type $address" threw me off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this;

```
<?php
class user {
    public $firstName='bulent';
    public $lastName ='kocaman';
    public $address;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->address = new address();
    }
}

class address{
    public $streetAddress=1;
    public $streetName=2;
    public $city=3;
    public $state=4;
    public $zip=5;
}

$user = new user();
print_r($user->address->zip);
?>
```

or

```
<?php
class user extends address{
    public $firstName='bulent';
    public $lastName ='kocaman';
}

class address{
    public $streetAddress=1;
    public $streetName=2;
    public $city=3;
    public $state=4;
    public $zip=5;
}

$user = new user();
print_r($user->zip);
?>
```

Comment: That's it!  Thank you very much!

Comment: No no no no no no!

Comment: @vascowhite why "no"? can you explain please?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to come back and expand this morning. Whilst your answer is technically correct and both examples will work, there are several issues with them. I strongly feel that we should be teaching new coders best practices from the start, and both your examples are bad practice, especially the second. Your first example instantiates a class in a constructor, which is an ant-pattern and prevents unit testing. In your second example you demonstrate extending a user from an address. A user is __not__ an address, a user __has__ an address, from this perspective your first example is better.

Answer (score 0):

```
$address = new $address();
```

I believe this is what you're looking for.

In PHP variable types are defined by the data they are assigned to. If you want $address in class 1 to be of type $address (class 2) then all you have to do is assign it to an instance of $address and it will take on that type. You will then be able to access any of the $address properties by using:

```
$user->address->zip
```

In short, yes you are on the right track. Look into adding constructors to your classes.

Comment: I don't believe they are asking how to instantiate an object, but whether the property of an object can be a reference to another object.

Comment: That would create a new address, but how does that establish that the parameter in the first class is of type $address?

Comment: "I want the $address parameter in the user class to be of type "address" defined by the second class." It seems like they are to me. I could be wrong though.

Comment: Thank you FireArrow5235!  You are correct, I didn't know how to build a constructor, which is what I was missing.

Comment: Glad I could help. To be fair, I could have been clearer on my initial posting. xD